# How to add multiple class to my intersectionObserver API?

Tags: javascript

```
 const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        const epa = entry.target.querySelector('.frontside');
         
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        epa.classList.add('animacion');
        return; // if we added the class, exit the function
        }
      
        // We're not intersecting, so remove the class!
        epa.classList.remove('animacion');
      });
      });
      
      observer.observe(document.querySelector('.vaimalandra'));
```

i try adding more classes like

```
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        const epa = entry.target.querySelector('.frontside, .img-form');
```

but it didn't work, so my guess is, what i need to do for make more classes and add like diferrents animations, where is "animacion" is an animation, and if i want add another how i will do it

Comment: `.querySelector()` will always only select ONE. `.querySelectorAll()` is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do like this.

```
const epa = entry.target.querySelectorAll('.frontside, .img-form');
```